# Split a population into two in Python

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

I have a list of values describing some population. The values are distributed into two peaks, as shown by the histogram below. 
[image: histogram with two distinct peaks]

Is there a simple way to automatically detect the "gap" in the centre of the distribution and split the initial list into two either side? Ideally using numpy if possible.

<s>Edit to add: Obviously I could just sort the list, iterate over it and split it at the first zero value, but</s> I'm hoping there's a more robust method which is "reasonable" even if the two peaks are not so clearly separated. Note the strikethro comment doesn't work, it's the histogram which has zero values, not the data, oops!

Comment: Only one split ? what if there's one more sample e.g.:at 0.4

Comment: Well, only having 2 sub-populations was part of the original assumption, but you have made me question it for my particular case!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a-priori informations about your distribution, e.g.: there are exactly two 'groups' of samples which are consecutives within the groups. Then you can use a naive algorithm: find the larger gap between two samples.

But the problem of spliting a population into subsets (clusters) is non-trivial, and is usually resolved via machine learning clustering algorithms: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to accept this as actually it answers the original question exactly, but propose a more flexible approach as an additional answer.

Answer (score 1):

Jean-loup's answer works well for the question as posed. However having a working, simple implementation allowed me to think about the problem a bit more and I'm posting the approach I came up with too in case it is useful.

```
def split_population2(seq, n_bins):
    """ Split a population into sub-populations

        Based on binning the data into n_bins and finding contigous groups of non-empty bins.

        Returns [lowest, ..., highest] all of which are sorted sequences
    """
    sorted_pop = sorted(seq)

    # bin the data into n_bins in a 2d structure, one sequence for each bin:
    _ , bins = np.histogram(sorted_pop, bins=n_bins)
    bin_indices = np.digitize(sorted_pop, bins)
    binned = []
    for i in range(len(bins)+1):
        binned.append([])
    for ix_bin, v in zip(bin_indices, sorted_pop):
        binned[ix_bin].append(v)

    # now join-up non-empty bins
    joined_bins = [[]] # so 2D, with initially 1 sub-list
    len_last_bin = 0
    for bin in binned:
        len_bin = len(bin)
        if len_bin == 0 and len_last_bin != 0: # will correctly handle the case where bin 0 is empty
            joined_bins.append([])
        if len_bin != 0:
            joined_bins[-1].extend(bin)
        len_last_bin = len_bin

    return joined_bins
```

I think this will work for cases where there are more than 2 sub-populations, and should be relatively robust for cases where the sub-populations are clearly separated. The disadvantage is that in some cases the answer will depend on the value selected for `n_bins`.

[image: original histogram]
[image: histogram showing sub-populations]